# dynamodb mapper, how to prevent duplicate records irrespective of the hash/range keys

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo db table where the hashKey is the userId and the range key is created timestamp.

We have some legacy code which is creating records in the dynamo db table, and that data has a field threadId (the primary key from the legacy db).

Occasionally (thanks to the underlying messaging platform) I get records with duplicate threadIds and in this case I only want one record in the production database.

i've tried setting a condition as follows:

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpr = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
      saveExpr.setExpected(new ImmutableMap.Builder()
          .put("threadId", new ExpectedAttributeValue()
              .withValue(new AttributeValue().withS(record.threadId))
                 .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE)).build());
      mapper.save(record, saveExpr);
```

however this doesn't work.  I'm not sure, but appears that if the userId/created (hash/range key) values are not identical, dynamo creates a new record irrespective of the save expression (which doesn't appear to match the documentation).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to prevent a duplicate record irrespective of the values of the hash/range keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following to resolve this:

```
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression();
    Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expectedAttributes =
        ImmutableMap.<String, ExpectedAttributeValue>builder()
            .put(THREAD_ID, new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(false)) //The threadId doesn't exist or is empty
            .build();
    saveExpression.setExpected(expectedAttributes);
```

Comment: I think the save expression works only on keys, is THREAD_ID a hash or range key in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
put("threadId", new ExpectedAttributeValue()
          .withValue(new AttributeValue().withS(record.threadId))
             .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE)).build());
```

to instead be:

```
put("threadId", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false))
```

More detail on the [AWS Blog](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1JADUVTWF7SP2/Specifying-Conditional-Constraints-with-Amazon-DynamoDB-Mapper)

Comment: sorry for the delay, this was close - i'll post an answer below.

Comment: @Peavers it's been there since June last year?